# Get a code line in c# when an exception occurs

Tags: c#, exception, stack-trace

I know that I ask too much, but I would like to know if it's possible to detect the code that triggers an exception, not only the Line and Column Numbers but even the source code string.

For example the result of a such operation could be:

--- Exception IndexOutOfBoundsException occurs at 'myArray[4]=tempValue;'

Comment: Sure. Use a debugger. It will provide all the tooling you need to actually see the line of code and all variables and their current values.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, compile your code is Debug configuration.

When an exception occurs, examine the [`StackTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

You can write an exception handler that logs this information or examine the property in your debugger.

The inherited [`Exception.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation will include any stack trace information that is available.